# Make var available to a inline function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create that function :

```
generateJson = function()
{
    var controls = {
        "invoicedate" : "invoicedate",
        "duedate" : "duedate"
    };

    var jsonLog = {};

    $.each(controls, function(index, value, jsonLog) {
      jsonLog[value] = "t";
    });
    $('#jsoncode').val(JSON.stringify(jsonLog));
}
```

I have an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'invoicedate' of undefined

How can I make the jsonLog var available in my inline function ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the third argument from the function you pass to `each` since:

1. The `each` won't pass anything into it
2. It masks the variable of the same name in the wider scope that you assigned the object to

Comment: My dear. you are right. I add it to test it and I forgot to remove it .. sorry for disturbing, it's rly obvious

Answer (score 2):

passing jsonLog as third argument is overriding or masking the previous actual jsonLog in parent scope

```
$.each(controls, function(index, value) {
      jsonLog[value] = "t";
    });
```